# How do I set a custom cache path for Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

I just installed Yarn and I'm trying to switch from npm.

I tried to set my cache path like this, but it wasn't successful:

```
yarn --cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
yarn global --cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
yarn global cache --cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
yarn cache --cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
yarn config set --cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
```

Here is the [documentation for yarn config](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/config).

Comment: if you do yarn --cache-folder <path> it does work and your cache will be in the specified path but it still doesn't change the default cache dir so this is not good enough and the docs says nothing about --cache-folder.

Comment: What I saw is that the folder `/usr/local/Caches/yarn` has been created wit a `.tmp` folder inside but all the actual cache files are still written to `~/.yarn-cache`

Comment: clear your previous cache and then try it again it should work, worked for me :)

Comment: @ANshulSharma didn't work for me. Were you in a project folder when you did this?

Comment: yes I was in the project folder

Answer (score 26):

The actual command is:

```
yarn config set cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
```

**(Note: no preceeding `--`)**

The [docs for `yarn cache`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache#toc-change-the-cache-path-for-yarn) show the various ways this can be set.

Comment: what is yarn default cache folder?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK:  It may depend on the O/S it is installed on, but you can get the default (if you haven't changed it) on your system with the command: `yarn cache dir`

Comment: Got it, thanks - any methods to verify `yarn cache` like `npm cache verify` command deos?

Comment: @BaneeIshaqueK:  Sorry, comments aren't designed for running commentaries.  If you can't find what you need in the docs I linked; or with Google, you can ask a separate question & odds are someone here can help you.

Comment: `yarn config list` can be used to verify the setting

Answer (score 0):

That one works for me:

```
yarn config set cacheFolder '/Users/"username"/.yarn/cache'
```

[yarn cacheFolder](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#cacheFolder)

[yarn config set](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/config/set/#usage)