# Ruby on Rails - Yarn directory location (as it is currently not writable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

**UPDATE 23/11/2018** 
Currently, I've done

```
yarn config set cache-folder /usr/local/Caches/yarn
```

And once I run `yarn install --check-files`, I get the error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/Caches'".
```

From this, I tried to then do `chmod -R 755 /usr/local/Caches/yarn`

And I get `chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/Caches/yarn': No such file or directory`

---

**UPDATE 23/11/2018**

Also, I've done `mkdir -p ~/home/james/.cache/yarn`
Then I've done `chmod -R 755 ~/home/james/.cache/yarn`

Then I obtain the error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/Caches'".
```

I've done: `chmod -R 755 /usr/local/Caches`

And then obtained: `chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/Caches': No such file or directory`

So, the methods I've done so far, have just not solved my issue.

---

I'm obtaining this error when I am trying to "fix" my yarn gem installation, and also installing webpacker.

"warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/home/james/.cache/yarn" because it is not writable."

I understand I need to change the directory permissions using chmod.

However, when I try and do that, using:

```
chmod -R 755 /home/james/.cache/yarn
```

I am told the /home/james/.cache/yarn directory is not found.

So, how exactly can I change this directory's permission?

Additional information: I'm running Windows 10, and I'm actually using Ubuntu on Windows, so to access my folders. I use Ubuntu and write:

```
james@DESKTOP-VP0F0PN:~$ cd /mnt/c/users/james/documents/github/personalwebsite
```

then I input the above chmod code after this. Also, to run the server:

```
james@DESKTOP-VP0F0PN:/mnt/c/users/james/documents/github/personalwebsite$ rails s
```

Comment: You can't change non-exists file's permission.

Comment: Did you `sudo` it too?

Comment: Or changing the cache folder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381112/how-do-i-set-a-custom-cache-path-for-yarn

Comment: Read your error messages mate, the first one was "error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/Caches'"." and you tried to chmod instead of mkdir

Answer (score 3):

You have a mix of relative and absolute paths in your examples. You're using a relative path (from `$HOME`, by using the `~` when you create, but the system is telling you it's looking in the absolute path).

You created the cache file with:

```
mkdir -p ~/home/james/.cache/yarn
```

You're trying to chmod this, however:

```
chmod -R 755 /home/james/.cache/yarn
```

You probably need to run:

```
mkdir -p /home/james/.cache/yarn # removed the tilde here
chmod -R 755 /home/james/.cache/yarn
```

I dropped the `~` in front of the mkdir, which would have created /home/james/home/james/.cache/yarn (assuming you're on Linux)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to create that directory in the first place?
Try

```
mkdir -p /home/james/.cache/yarn
```

and then check yarn installation again.
Updated according to @jay-dorsey comment

Comment: Assuming the user is on Linux (because macOS uses `/Users/james` for home directories), this should actually be `mkdir -p /home/james/.cache/yarn` otherwise it creates the folder `/home/james/home/james/.cache/yarn`